# Update snapcraft to 2.15

Tags: ubuntu-core, snap

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 upgraded from Ubuntu 14.04, whenever i install snapcraft it install snapcraft 2.8.4. 
(I am installing using ``sudo apt-get install snapcraft'' )

I want to install snapcraft v2.15, i have also tried setup.py option (code downloaded from github)

Any help will appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You want to enable `xenial-updates` for `universe` packages in your apt sources.list, you can do this either by going into `/etc/apt/sources.list` and adding `xenial-updates`. Here are some lines to add to your `/etc/apt/sources.list` that would enable `-updates` for `main`, `universe` and `multiverse` using the main archive:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates multiverse
```

Then run

```
apt update
apt install snapcraft
```

Alternatively,

- open "Software & Updates"
- go to the "Updates" tab
- click on "Recommended updates (xenial-updates)"
  [image: Software & Updates on the Updates tab]
- `apt install snapcraft` from a terminal